# Reporting Services Hyperlink to Report in Another Project

Tags: reporting-services, hyperlink

I need to set up a hyperlink in a report in one reporting services project to a report in another project that's part of the same solution.  The standard "Specify a Report" option allows linkage only to reports within the project.  Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the info I needed at: 
http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1336

> Passing the parameter entirely through HTML
>
> Start over with your browser at the ProdColor prompt. Instead of choosing the color from the >dropdown, add the following at the end of the URL:
>
> &ProdColor=Green.